# How to execute QWebEngine in Python function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebenginepage

I have a QWebEngine class tor read webpages and create BeautifulSoup for them.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)
        self.soup = []

    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        return True

    def processCurrentPage(self, html):
        url = self.url().toString()
        self.soup.append(BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml'))
        if not self.fetchNext():
            QtWidgets.qApp.quit()

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.processCurrentPage)
```

Here is another function to call `WebPage` class:

```
def get_soup(urls):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(urls)
    return webpage.soup
```

Here is the `main`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    urls = ["http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket_c.aspx?t=sh", "http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket_c.aspx?t=sz"]      
    soups = get_soup(urls)
```

However, the program restarts when I executed the program.

What should be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that I had already had and analyzing I found that the QApplication is destroyed before QWebEnginePage making the QWebEngineProfile is deleted, and in this case causing QWebEnginePage crashes. The solution is to make the app have a greater scope by making it a global variable.

On the other hand you have to call exec_() so that the eventloop that allows the operation of the signals

```py
# ...
app = None

def get_soup(urls):
    global app
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(urls)
    app.exec_()
    return webpage.soup
# ...
```

---

**Note:** It seems that the [QTBUG-75547](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75547) related to this problem has been solved for Qt5>=5.12.4 so probably in a next release of [PyQtWebEngine](https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/) that bug will no longer be observed.